# Avoid scrolling back with smoothScrollToPosition or setSelection

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

When i use getListView().smoothScrollToPosition in a ListFragment and the row is visible in screen, the listview always has scrolling back from the top.

What i can do to avoid scrolling back when i selected the same row or when the row is visible in screen?

Sorry my bad english

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this work:

```
public void scrollToPosition(final int position) {

    View v = getListView().getChildAt(0);
    int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

    getListView().setSelectionFromTop(position, top);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (position < getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition()
        || position > getListView().getLastVisiblePosition())
{
    getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(position);
}
```

Comment: this not work :( ... getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition() and getListView().getLastVisiblePosition() always returns 0 and 5 respectively